# Can we have two different jsf version in same EAR

Tags: jsf, ear

I am using JSF1.1 for my project. The workspace includes EAR, Dynamic web module and Java projects.

Now i want to have one more Dynamic web module with JSF2.1. it is possible?

and Is this a good practice to have two different versions of JSF in the same EAR.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Each web module within the EAR can have it's own JSF version as long as the dependencies are packaged within each WAR. You will want to ensure a parent-last classloading approach as well.